# Android Game Development - How can I fill a circle with a repeated pattern?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently developing a game for Android.

As part of the game, I need to have a circle that increases and decreases in size, but not with a simple single-colour paint fill.

Instead, is there a way I could dynamically draw a circle onto a canvas then fill it with a given image (probably another bitmap - tiled, in order to fill the image)?

Many thanks in advance,
Will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do a simple Canvas.drawCircle(), but using a Paint with a [BitmapShader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader.html).

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I'm trying to do. I'll attempt it later when I get my App working again (I've somehow broken it), and if it works, I'll "accepted answer"-ify your response. Thanks very much!