# How do I make a pattern fill of the path of a text in android?

Tags: android, paint, android-canvas

I am trying to generate the below effect programmatically by altering between the two states over time

[image: State-1 image] [image: State-2 image]

Basically in the first image (state #1), I want to get the *path* of the text filled with my own custom bitmap (a red circle in case of the example above) and those should repeat after a fixed distance (which happens to be the same as the diameter of the red circle in this case).
In the second image (state #2), the red circles take the alternative pattern and their locations are those that were blank spaces in state #1.

From [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046304/android-game-development-how-can-i-fill-a-circle-with-a-repeated-pattern) I gather I can  use `BitmapShaders` on my paint. The following is the code that I have come up with for one state. However I am stuck and unable to think as to how can I achieve this.

```
public void drawText(String text, int x, int y) {
    Paint defPaint = new Paint();
    defPaint.setTextSize(100);
    defPaint.setStrokeWidth(0);

    defPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

    defPaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(
            ((AndroidPixmap) Assets.redCircle).bitmap, TileMode.REPEAT,
            TileMode.REPEAT));

    Path path = new Path();
    defPaint.getTextPath(text, 0, text.length(), x, y, path);
    canvas.drawPath(path, defPaint);
}
```

I have also tried using the `PathEffects` but have not been successful with them either.